# Extend a Dynamic Trait?

Tags: algorithm, scala

I'm new to Scala and I do not know exactly how to call this question, but basically I have this:

```
   trait Hi {
      protected val hi : String = "Hi"

   }

   trait HowAre {
      protected val howare : String = "How Are you?"

   }

   trait Text{
     protected val text :String = "Any Text"
   }

   class SeeText () extends Text {

     def SeeString() = {
        println(text)
     }

   }

   class SeeHi () extends Hi {

     def SeeString() = {
        println(hi)
     }

   }

   class SeeHowAre () extends HowAre {

     def SeeString() = {
        println(howare)
     }

   }
```

I have the same function in each class to show the string, I do not want that, I want to use a single class that has only one function and shows the string, I thought about it:

```
   trait Hi {
      protected val hi : String = "Hi"
      def getString() : String = {hi}

   }

   trait HowAre {
      protected val howare : String = "How Are you?"
       def getString() : String = {howare}

   }

   trait Text{
     protected val text :String = "Any Text"
       def getString() : String = {text}
   }

   class SeeGeneral() extends Text with Hi with HowAre{
        def SeeString()={
          println( getString() )
        }
   }
```

But how do I control String to show? Can a class extend a single trait dynamically? the idea is not to create a class for each trait and not to program more code, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base trait that implements `getString()` and have all your traits extend that trait:

```
trait SupportsGetString {
  def getString: String
}

trait Hi extends SupportsGetString {
  protected val hi : String = "Hi"
  def getString() : String = {hi}

}

trait HowAre extends SupportsGetString  {
  protected val howare : String = "How Are you?"
  def getString() : String = {howare}
}

trait Text extends SupportsGetString {
  protected val text :String = "Any Text"
    def getString() : String = {text}
}
```

Then your general function can accept an instance of the base trait.

```
def seeString(a: SupportsGetString) = a.getString
```

Sometimes, you can't have a shared base class. Perhaps, maybe one of your traits is provided by a third party and can't be changed.  When that happens, you can use typeclasses. This technique lets you describe the behavior of extracting a string from a type `A` outside the type:

```
// A trait that knows how to get some inner string from a type A
trait GetString[A] {
  def getString(a: A): String
}
```

Now, let's define a few values of this trait for the types you have:

```
object GetString {
    implicit val hiGetString: GetString[Hi] = new GetString[Hi] {
        def getString(a: Hi): String = a.hi
    }
    implicit val howAreGetString: GetString[HowAre] = new GetString[HowAre] {
        def getString(a: HowAre): String = a.howare
    }
}
```

Now, here's how you can write a function that gets a string out of any `A` you have an implicit `GetString[A]` for:

```
def getIt[A](a: A)(implicit getter: GetString[A]): String = 
    getter.getString(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are actually asking, but I think, you are looking for *stackable trait* pattern:

```
 trait Text {
   def text: String = ""
 }

 trait Hi extends Text {
   override def text = super.text + "Hi"
 }

 trait HowAre extends Text { 
   override def text = super.text + ", how are"
 }

 trait You extends Text {
    override def text = super.text + " you?"
 }  

 class It extends Hi with HowAre with You {
    def seeString = println(text)
 }
```